# unable to make proper ui like playstore

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

Hi i am developing an app where i have to make a ui like playtstore for that i saw this [tutorial](https://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html) but now my problem is that i'm unable to add different
text for different rows and second is that even after setting height and width it doesnt seem to be get affected.
Please if someone can help me out here i'm stuck at this point
my code is as follows

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            int[] images = {R.drawable.vancouver,R.drawable.party,R.drawable.hands_ip,R.drawable.dj};
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            allSampleData = new ArrayList<SectionDataModel>();
            createDummyData();

            HorizontalAdapter firstAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter(images);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
            NestedScrollView nestedScrollView = view.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
            llm = new LadderLayoutManager(1.5f, 0.85f, LadderLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL).
                    setChildDecorateHelper(new LadderLayoutManager
                            .DefaultChildDecorateHelper(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.item_max_elevation)));
            llm.setChildPeekSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    30, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
            //llm.setReverse(true);
            /*llm.setMaxItemLayoutCount(5);

            rcv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rcv);
            rcv.setLayoutManager(llm);

            new LadderSimpleSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(rcv);
            adapter = new HSAdapter();
            rcv.setAdapter(adapter);

            multi_scroll_recyclerview = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.multi_scroll_recyclerview);
            multi_scroll_recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            multi_scroll_layout_manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
            multi_scroll_recyclerview.setLayoutManager(multi_scroll_layout_manager);
            multi_scroll_adapter = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(getActivity(),allSampleData);
            multi_scroll_recyclerview.setAdapter(multi_scroll_adapter);
            multi_scroll_recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);*/






       /* MultiSnapRecyclerView firstRecyclerView = (MultiSnapRecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.first_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager firstManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        firstRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(firstManager);
        firstRecyclerView.setAdapter(firstAdapter);

        HorizontalAdapter secondAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter(images);
        MultiSnapRecyclerView secondRecyclerView =(MultiSnapRecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.second_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager secondManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        secondRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(secondManager);
        secondRecyclerView.setAdapter(secondAdapter);

        HorizontalAdapter thirdAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter(images);
        MultiSnapRecyclerView thirdRecyclerView = (MultiSnapRecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.third_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager thirdManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        thirdRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(thirdManager);
        thirdRecyclerView.setAdapter(thirdAdapter);*/


            return view;

        }
        public void createDummyData() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

                SectionDataModel dm = new SectionDataModel();
                dm.setHeaderTitle("Clubs");
                dm.setHeadertitle2("Lounge");
                dm.setHeadertitle3("Cafe");
                dm.setHeadertitle4("Rooftop");
                ArrayList<SingleItemModel> singleItem = new ArrayList<SingleItemModel>();
                for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
                    singleItem.add(new SingleItemModel("Item " + j, "URL " + j));
                }

                dm.setAllItemsInSection(singleItem);

                allSampleData.add(dm);//line which is causing issue

            }
        }
code for adapter

    public class SectionListDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionListDataAdapter.SingleItemRowHolder> {

        private ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList;
        private Context mContext;

        public SectionListDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList) {
            this.itemsList = itemsList;
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_single_card, null);
            SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
            return mh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

            SingleItemModel singleItem = itemsList.get(i);

            holder.tvTitle.setText(singleItem.getName());


           /* Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .error(R.drawable.bg)
                    .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
        }

        public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            protected TextView tvTitle;

            protected ImageView itemImage;


            public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                this.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);


                view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), tvTitle.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });


            }

        }

    }

My code for model class

    public class SectionDataModel {
        private String headerTitle,headertitle2,headertitle3,headertitle4;
        private ArrayList<SingleItemModel> allItemsInSection;


        public SectionDataModel() {

        }
        public SectionDataModel(String headerTitle, ArrayList<SingleItemModel> allItemsInSection) {
            this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
            this.allItemsInSection = allItemsInSection;
        }



        public String getHeaderTitle() {
            return headerTitle;
        }

        public String getHeadertitle2() {
            return headertitle2;
        }

        public String getHeadertitle3() {
            return headertitle3;
        }

        public String getHeadertitle4() {
            return headertitle4;
        }

        public void setHeaderTitle(String headerTitle) {
            this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
        }

        public void setHeadertitle2(String headertitle2) {
            this.headertitle2 = headertitle2;
        }

        public void setHeadertitle3(String headertitle3) {
            this.headertitle3 = headertitle3;
        }

        public void setHeadertitle4(String headertitle4) {
            this.headertitle4 = headertitle4;
        }

        public ArrayList<SingleItemModel> getAllItemsInSection() {
            return allItemsInSection;
        }

        public void setAllItemsInSection(ArrayList<SingleItemModel> allItemsInSection) {
            this.allItemsInSection = allItemsInSection;
        }

    }

listitem.xml

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnMore"
                android:text="Sample title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="27sp" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnMore"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_more_horiz_black_24dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />


    </LinearLayout>

main fragment.xml

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

            android:id="@+id/multi_scroll_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

listsinglecard.xml

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="65dp"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/itemImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/vancouver" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/itemImage"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="Sample title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```